# how to convert a number to date in oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a excel format dataset that need to be imported to a table, one column is a date, but the data is stored in number format, such as 41275, when importing data, i tried to choose data format yyyy-mm-dd, it gives an error: not a valid month, also tried MM/DD/YYYY also error: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month. does anyone know what is this number and how can i convert it to a date format when importing it into the database?Thanks!

Comment: what excel gives you is the number of days since January 1st 1900 ...

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 I don't quiet understand, how to conver the number to a date format? does that number means a certain date?

Comment: I think the best way to change the cell type to text, maybe use an other column for it `=text(Date_col,'yyyy.mm.dd')` than export csv. Now you have a delimetered csv where the dates yyyy.mm.dd and now you can easly import without bugs. Or if you familiar with java write a simply code with excel api, read all the lines and insert with jdbc. (I use this if i import huge amount and need to get dates, if small amount i just simply text the cells and import without problems)

Answer (score 2):

The expression (with respect to the Excel's leap year bug AmmoQ mentions) you are looking for is:

```
case
    when yourNumberToBeImported <= 59 then date'1899-12-31' + yourNumberToBeImported
    else date'1899-12-30' + yourNumberToBeImported
end
```

Then, you may either

- Create a (global) temporary table in your Oracle DB, load your data from the Excel to the table and then reload the data from the temporary table to your target table with the above calculation included.

or you may

- Load the data from the Excel to a persistent table in your Oracle DB and create a view over the persistent table which would contain the above calculation.

Answer (score 0):

The number you got is the excel representation of a certain date ...

excel stores a date as the number of days, starting to count at a certain date ... to be precise:

1 = 1-JAN-1900
2 = 2-JAN-1900
...
30 = 30-JAN-1900

so, to get your excel number into an oracle date, you might want to try something like this...

```
to_date('1899-12-31','yyyy-mm-dd') + 41275
```

Comment: Beware of Excel's 1900-leapyear-bug ;-) http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/214326/en-us

Comment: And beware of the `date_add` function which does not exist in Oracle and of the incorrect spelling of the `interval` literal. ;-)

Comment: @nop77svk well, as far as i can see that date_add is no problem with oracle ... at least for days, it comes down to "+"

Comment: As far as I can see: `ORA-00904: "DATE_ADD": invalid identifier`

Comment: Then, what you did you mean by giving the asker a nonworking piece of code? :-)

Anyway, I see that you updated your answer. Now it looks fine.

Comment: "something like" means i neither have an oracle dbms at hand right now, nor was in the mood to get a manual  ... it was my intention to point out what OP should do to get his numbers converted ... not necessarily providing copy-pasta-code ...

Comment: @ammoQ _"Excel's 1900-leapyear-bug"_ I don't have Excel at hand to test it, but given this bug, how is represented 1st or march 1900? As day 59 or 60?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux, according to Excel, 28.02.1900 = 59, 29.02.1900 = 60, 01.03.1900 = 61.